# ArcPy- Cumulative Months - ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro

I have this script that creates a feature class for every month from 2014-2017. However, I would now like to have the monthly data add on to each other. For example, instead of it going [Jan, Feb, Mar] I would want it to go [Jan, Jan+Feb, Jan+Feb+Mar]. However, I do not know how to do this in ArcPy and I can't find any examples online anywhere.

Here is my code:

```
import arcpy
import datetime 
from datetime import timedelta
import time
import calendar

# Set environment settings
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\arcGIS_Shared\Python\CenterHeatMaps5.gdb"

#Declare variables
fc = 'Open_GoHealth_Centers'
fields = ['USER_market_id','USER_GoHealth_ID','USER_GoHealth_Center_Name','USER_Opening_Date']
fieldname = 'USER_market_id'

# Set Markets to loop through
markets = [1000,2000,3000,4000]
# Set Years to loop through
years = [2014,2015,2016,2017]
# Set Months to loop through
months = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]

sqlclause = (None, 'Order By USER_market_id, USER_GoHealth_ID')

#returns last day of each month
def last_day_of_month(any_day):
    next_month = any_day.replace(day=28) + datetime.timedelta(days=4)
    return next_month - datetime.timedelta(days=next_month.day)

for market in markets:
    print (market)

    #Define WHERE clause statement
    whereclause = """{} = """.format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(fc, fieldname)) + str(market)

    for year in years:
        print (year)
        for month in months:
            print (month)
            with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(in_table = fc, field_names = fields, where_clause=whereclause, sql_clause=(None, 'ORDER BY USER_market_id, USER_GoHealth_ID')) as cursor:
                #Loop through each row established in cursor
                for row in (cursor):
                    # Set local variables for the FeatureClasstoFeatureClass tool
                    inFeatures = "PatientVisitsGeocoded"
                    outLocation = r"C:\arcGIS_Shared\Python\CenterHeatMaps5.gdb"
                    outFeatureClass = "PatientVisits{0}_{1}_{3}_{2}".format(row[0], row[2], month, year)
                    delimitedfield = arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(arcpy.env.workspace,"USER_CenterID")
                    expression = """{0} = {1} AND USER_DOSMonth = '{2}' AND USER_DOSYear = {3}""".format(delimitedfield, row[1], calendar.month_abbr[month], year)


    #               Execute FeatureClassToFeatureClass tool
    #               This If statement determines if the Opening_Date of the respective center is before the last day of the month being run.
    #               If it is, the feature class is copied, if not, the feature class is skipped.
                    if last_day_of_month(datetime.date(year, month, 1)) >= row[3].date():
                        arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(inFeatures, outLocation, outFeatureClass, expression)

                        #Print Results
                        print(row[2])
```

Update-----------
I have tried using `NumPy` and `cumsum`, but I know get the following error

```
if last_day_of_month(datetime.date(year, np.cumsum(months), 1)) >= row[3].date():

TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

At first I thought this was because I was using a list for months instead of an array, but then I converted the list to an array (or at least I think I did) and I still get the same error.

Do you think this method will work?

Here is my new code:

```
 import arcpy
    import datetime 
    import time
    import calendar
    import numpy as np
    from numpy import array
    from datetime import timedelta

    # Set environment settings
    arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\arcGIS_Shared\Python\CenterHeatMaps6.gdb"

    #Declare variables
    fc = 'Open_GoHealth_Centers'
    fields = ['USER_market_id','USER_GoHealth_ID','USER_GoHealth_Center_Name','USER_Opening_Date']
    fieldname = 'USER_market_id'

    # Set Markets to loop through
    markets = [4000]
    # Set Years to loop through
    years = [2017]
    # Set Months to loop through
    months = array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12])

    #Cumulative Sum of Months
    np.cumsum(months)

    sqlclause = (None, 'Order By USER_market_id, USER_GoHealth_ID')

    #returns last day of each month
    def last_day_of_month(any_day):
        next_month = any_day.replace(day=28) + datetime.timedelta(days=4)
        return next_month - datetime.timedelta(days=next_month.day)

    for market in markets:


        #Define WHERE clause statement
        whereclause = """{} = """.format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(fc, fieldname)) + str(market)

        for year in years:

            for month in np.cumsum(months):
                with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(in_table = fc, field_names = fields, where_clause=whereclause, sql_clause=(None, 'ORDER BY USER_market_id, USER_GoHealth_ID')) as cursor:
                    #Loop through each row established in cursor
                    for row in (cursor):
                        # Set local variables for the FeatureClasstoFeatureClass tool
                        inFeatures = "PatientVisitsGeocoded"
                        outLocation = r"C:\arcGIS_Shared\Python\CenterHeatMaps6.gdb"
                        outFeatureClass = "PatientVisits{0}_{1}_{3}_{2}".format(row[0], row[2], np.cumsum(months), year)
                        delimitedfield = arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(arcpy.env.workspace,"USER_CenterID")
                        expression = """{0} = {1} AND USER_DOSMonth = '{2}' AND USER_DOSYear = {3}""".format(delimitedfield, row[1], np.cumsum(month), year) #calendar.month_abbr[month]


        #               Execute FeatureClassToFeatureClass tool
        #               This If statement determines if the Opening_Date of the respective center is before the last day of the month being run.
        #               If it is, the feature class is copied, if not, the feature class is skipped.
                        if last_day_of_month(datetime.date(year, np.cumsum(months), 1)) >= row[3].date():
                            arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(inFeatures, outLocation, outFeatureClass, expression)
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to select out additional details each pass through your loop, you will need to update your WHERE clause. Perhaps create a list of the desired WHERE clauses based on your year and month list? Or put your WHERE clause into the loop and modify it there.

Comment: Could you give me an example of a "list of desired WHERE clauses"? I'm not exactly sure what that would look like